# How to copy body of Outlook e-mail and paste into Excel using Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-word

I am looking to bring data from an Outlook message into Access using Excel as a "middleman" for ease of referencing the data. I've been able to copy from Outlook to Excel, and import data from Excel into Access.

I'm looking to handle the entire process from Access.

The line of code, in Outlook VBA, to copy the e-mail body is not working in Access VBA. I'm thinking I have a problem with a variable dim, or set.

The error is

> Run Time 287 Application-defined or object-defined error.

I can close the open e-mail with VBA from Access, so I know the applications are talking to one another.

```vb
Private Sub cmdNewFromEmail_Click()
    
    Dim strWhere As String
    
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String
    
    Dim objol As Outlook.Application
    Dim MyInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim CurrentMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    
    filePath = "S:\UserNanme\" & "Excel Test File" & ".xlsx"
    Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
    
    'Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set objol = New Outlook.Application
    Set MyInspector = Outlook.ActiveInspector
    Set objItem = MyInspector.CurrentItem
    
    xl.Visible = True
    'OL.Visible = True
    
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

    'Setting up a new file in Access
    Me.File_Number = Nz(DMax("File_Number", "ClaimInfo1", strWhere), 0) + 1
               
    Me.Invoice_Number = Me.File_Number & "-01"
               
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
               
    'Binds Client Billing tab to Invoicing form when setting up new file
    Me.SubformContainer.SourceObject = "Appraisals_Subform2"

    'Sets focus on the appropriate tab.
     Forms!Invoicing_Form.TabCtlEval = 0
    
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    With objItem
        
        'Set CurrentMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        
        ' *** This is the line causing the problem.
        ' Other things I've tried are commented out.***
        Set CurrentMessage = MyInspector.WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy    

        'Set CurrentMessage = MyInspector
        'CurrentMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
        'CurrentMessage.Close olSave
        'CurrentMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText
        'CurrentMessage.Copy
          
    End With
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------
    With xlSheet
        
        .Range("A1").Select
        .Paste
        
        .Range("F5").Value = "Claim:  "
        .Range("G5").Formula = "=INDEX(B1:B100,MATCH(F5,A1:A100,0))"
                    
    End With
    
    Me.Claim_Number = Range("G5")
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing error?

Comment: @june7 the one the OP marked "this is the line causing the problem "

Comment: That line is referencing a lot of objects.  I'd suggest breaking it down by Diming and assigning each layer in turn,  to see where it breaks

Comment: @chrisneilsen I appreciate the suggestion.  It sounds reasonable enough, but I'm not entire sure how to go about it.  The line was built with the intellisense.  I could maybe dim Myrange as a Range, and FormattedText as String, but what would I do with WordEditor?  And how would I then piece them all together?

Comment: You’re attempting to assign a method (`Copy`) to an object variable. Just delete `Set CurrentMessage = `

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks, but it still throws the same error on the same line.

Comment: Intellisense does not give me .Range. I have code that pulls details from Outlook messages and it does not use WordEditor.

Comment: Code is from https://www.devhut.net/category/ms-access/ms-access-outlook-automation/. `.body` returns message body.

Comment: @June7 You are correct... Sorry...  I've tried so many things in the last 24 hours, my head is swimming.  Intellisense stops after .WordEditor.  I found the .Range.FormattedText.Copy part online, and it does work in Outlook, just not in Access. I suspect this has to be something really simple, I just don't have the training or experience to understand intuitively what it is.

Comment: Why involve Excel? Message body can be saved directly to a LongText (Memo) field in Access table. Access could even set a link to Outlook folder and then queries could pull from linked table.

Comment: @June7 .Body returns the message body in what context?  I'm guessing there's more to it.  Currentmessage.body  followed by CurrentMessage.Copy doesn't work.

Comment: It would be a string so just save the string to a variable or to field in table or to cell in Excel. `strBody = .body`

Comment: @June7 Regarding the involvement of Excel.  Undoubtedly a true coder might be able to pull off what you are suggesting.  Unfortunately I don't have that skill set, and I don't have the luxury of the time it would take to learn through trial and error.  Excel makes referencing easy. A piece of data is located in a certain cell, and I bring it into a certain Access field.

Comment: You have code that puts focus on a new record of form. Should email body go into field of that record? Populating 'certain field' can be as simple as `Me.fieldname = .body`. Once Outlook automation code is fixed, think you will find the Excel superfluous. Trial and error is what you have been doing. The copy/paste action is not working and not necessary.

Comment: @June7 I have a dozen or more separate pieces of data from the e-mail body (I removed all but 1 to keep the code readable). If I brought the entire body into an Access field, I'd have no idea how to parse it from there.

Comment: I presume that's what the INDEX() formula accomplishes. String manipulation in VBA can be done but that's a topic for another question. So try simply setting cell A1 value to the .body string instead of copy/paste.

Comment: Instead of: .Range.FormattedText.Copy use is: .Range.Copy

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing the line
`Set CurrentMessage = MyInspector.WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy`
with
`objItem.Body = CurrentMessage.Body`
?

Also there is no need having the `With objItem` `End With` block, as you are not using it anywhere. You could completely remove it.